# What is "slice" being used for in this code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adapt some code found here:

http://gregtrowbridge.com/a-basic-pathfinding-algorithm/

However, I can't figure out what the "slice" method is being used for on line #92. Can anyone tell me? It is being called without any arguments. Thanks.

[edit]

StackOverflow is not letting me post the code, saying there is too much of it, sorry. Here is the relevant snippet though. Take a look at line #4.

```
// Explores the grid from the given location in the given
// direction
var exploreInDirection = function(currentLocation, direction, grid) {
  var newPath = currentLocation.path.slice();
  newPath.push(direction);

  var dft = currentLocation.distanceFromTop;
  var dfl = currentLocation.distanceFromLeft;

  if (direction === 'North') {
    dft -= 1;
  } else if (direction === 'East') {
    dfl += 1;
  } else if (direction === 'South') {
    dft += 1;
  } else if (direction === 'West') {
    dfl -= 1;
  }

  var newLocation = {
    distanceFromTop: dft,
    distanceFromLeft: dfl,
    path: newPath,
    status: 'Unknown'
  };
  newLocation.status = locationStatus(newLocation, grid);

  // If this new location is valid, mark it as 'Visited'
  if (newLocation.status === 'Valid') {
    grid[newLocation.distanceFromTop][newLocation.distanceFromLeft] = 'Visited';
  }

  return newLocation;
};
```

Comment: It's creating a copy of the array so it doesn't mutate the currentLocation array

Comment: Here is a reference that explains it fully https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice returns a shallow copy of the original array, so all operations done on the copy do not change the original. When you assign an array to a variable it is really just giving the new variable the array's location in memory.

So the slice method is a good way to make an entirely new array that is just the exact same as the original. Also, keep in mind when comparing arrays the === method checks equality by comparing their address in memory so the sliced array will not be considered equal to the original even if they are the exact same.

To Demonstrate this:

```
var orig = [1, 2, 3];
var copy = orig;
console.log(copy === orig); // ---> true


var orig = [1, 2, 3];
var copy = orig.slice();
console.log(copy === orig); // ---> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `.slice()` method makes a (shallow) copy of an array.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.slice()` is often used this way to return a copy of the array so that the original array isn't altered by the caller. I believe the returned array is only a shallow copy, so this works for arrays or primitives, but with arrays of objects it may not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the array into a new one, shallow copy the original and return the copied one as its return value.

> slice does not alter the original array. It returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the returned array as follows:
>
> - For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.
> - For strings, numbers and booleans (not String, Number and Boolean objects), slice copies the values into the new array. Changes to the string, number or boolean in one array do not affect the other array.